# How to fix wishlist product deletion issue in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.5

I am using magento2.3.5 in that when i am go to the Wishlist section in customer dashboard and try to delete the product but it is not deleted please help me to fix this , i am using magento2.3.5 default theme.

Comment: show what error  come when delete product.

Comment: Nothing error come when i try to delete just page go on top @Msquare

Comment: I try in magento2.3.4 and magento2.3.5 in both version it do the same thing

Comment: Kindly check your console when you click on delete or when wish page loads check it for any error.